# Using Promise with async/await

Tags: typescript, async-await, es6-promise

I'm starting with async/await things in TypeScript and I have few questions about it. I wrote this function to get ArrayBuffer from Blob.

```
async function readAsArrayBuffer(blob: Blob): Promise<ArrayBuffer> {
    return new Promise<ArrayBuffer>((resolve, reject) => {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.addEventListener('load', e => resolve((<FileReader>e.target).result));
        reader.addEventListener('error', e => reject((<FileReader>e.target).error));
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
    });
}
```

So...

1. Do I really need `async` keyword before this function? I think, it does nothing...
2. Should I create new FileReader in Promise executor function scope or at readAsArrayBuffer scope level? (...or it doesn't matter?)
3. What I wrote is two functions nested in function nested in function. Am I doing something wrong? :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do I really need async keyword before this function? I think, it does nothing...

Nope. You only really need the `async` keyword if you use `await` inside your function body.

> Should I create new FileReader in Promise executor function scope or at readAsArrayBuffer scope level? (...or it doesn't matter?)

I would recommend keeping most of the actual code inside the executor function. The advantage is that if you have a *synchronous* exception (e.g. if `new FileReader()` were to `throw` on construction), the executor will catch that and turn it into an asynchronous promise rejection. If you put it outside the executor function, then your function would throw a synchronous exception. This would be confusing to use, since you'd have to handle both synchronous and asynchronous exceptions separately.

> What I wrote is two functions nested in function nested in function. Am I doing something wrong? :-)

It's fine. This is quite a common pattern when you're writing a promise wrapper around a non-promise API. The advantage is that you can now use this wrapper with `await` and avoid nested functions in other parts of your code. :-)

Comment: @trincot Yup, [see MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise): _"If an error is thrown in the executor function, the promise is rejected. The return value of the executor is ignored."_ Note that Chrome logs "Uncaught (in promise) my error" when you run this from the dev console, but this is actually because of the default uncaught promise rejection handler. Try putting a `try..catch` around it to see the difference compared to just `throw "my error"`.

Comment: Indeed, you're right. The output I saw in FireFox was less clear than in Chrome.

Answer (score 3):

> 1. Do I really need async keyword before this function? I think, it does nothing...

No, you only need `async` when the function uses the `await` keyword, which would make the function execute asynchronously, which is not the case in your function: it executes synchronously to completion. The asynchronous part is only in the triggering of the callbacks, which is not what the `async` keyword is about.

> 2. Should I create new FileReader in Promise executor function scope or at readAsArrayBuffer scope level? (...or it doesn't matter?)

Best practice is to define variables in the smallest scope that is needed for the job. Although it would work either way, as you have it now is better.

> 3. What I wrote is two functions nested in function nested in function. Am I doing something wrong? :-)

Nothing wrong with it.